# Why is there a error if I import pygame, although i have the pack installed?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
```

Why is there an error shown, but i have installed pygame 3 times!

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: `from thingy.thingy import *`

Comment: Too few information. Don't write this command in one line. Those are two different commands `import pygame` and `from pygame import *`. What is the error exactly? How do you execute the program?

Comment: Any chance your own file or folder is called `pygame`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take `pip show pygame` in the terminal to get where you have installed the `pygame`.

Then check which python interpreter you have selected from the bottom-right on the VSCode.

If it does not match, click the `python interpreter` to switch the python interpreter.

Comment: Good idea, Steven! I appreciate your help. The interpreter of python helped